# Error when saving user record: "attempt to add owning ref to user rec"

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have added a reference in user record to an `UserSetting` record. And when I try to save it, get an error:

```
publicDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(userRecordID, completionHandler: {userRecord, error in

 if error == nil {

        var sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
        if userRecord.objectForKey("userSetting") == nil {

        userRecord.setObject(CKReference(recordID: CKRecordID(recordName: userSettingRecordName), action: .DeleteSelf), forKey:"userSetting")

        publicDatabase.saveRecord(userRecord, completionHandler: { userRecord2, error in
```

ERROR:

```
Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x147597d0; _4b7ba4c20299131a41c29cf45b1493f0:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> to server: attempt to add owning ref to user rec
```

The strange that from `Dashboard` I can add reference to user record:

[image]

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added reference to user record can not be `.DeleteSelf` only `.None`, because user record can not delete.